Displaying every value present in more than 5% of records in a pie chart
Current situation
I have a pie chart representing the values of source.keyword, with the metric being sum(size) (source and size being fields present in every record). The current setting is that it shows the "Top 5 values of source.keyword".
Goal
Modifying said pie chart to show every value of source.keyword that is present in at least 5% of the records.
My questions
Is there a direct way to achieve this? In the event that a direct way is not accessible, is there a workaround?
